# Use XML to retrieve/insert data into SQL database

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have some spare time so I was reading about xml
it says here:

XML can be generated from a database
with this code:

```
<%
response.ContentType = "text/xml"
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
conn.open server.mappath("/db/database.mdb")

sql="select fname,lname from tblGuestBook"
set rs=Conn.Execute(sql)

response.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>")
response.write("<guestbook>")
while (not rs.EOF)
response.write("<guest>")
response.write("<fname>" & rs("fname") & "</fname>")
response.write("<lname>" & rs("lname") & "</lname>")
response.write("</guest>")
rs.MoveNext()
wend

rs.close()
conn.close()
response.write("</guestbook>")
%>
```

after I read from the table and change data that I want, can I add the new data in the sql table again?

Comment: There is no **SQL database** -- **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... but stuff like what you're asking about is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: i will create a table using sql server 2008 and i will read and write from this table, is it possible ?

Comment: Sure it's possible - but I'm not very clear yet on what you're trying to do, what your XML sample data will look like, what your table(s) looks like etc. .... you need to provide a bit more detail on what you're trying to accomplish (and what you have tried yourself)

Comment: i was working or start to work on a local program, part of it was that the user fill a form, and that form will be saved into database.mdb, all people told me its better to do it with PHP, but i dont like PHP, i found that it might be done with xml + html + javascript , so is it possible ?